# What's the difference between "you do have to" and "you have to"

Tags: do-support

Can we use them interchangeably or there are situations where only one of them is correct?

Comment: ***Don't*** use the "do-support" version unless you have some specific reason. For example, I used it in my first sentence here because it's part of the idiomatic way of issuing a ***negated*** imperative - ***Do not use this***, as opposed to the simple non-negated imperative ***Use this***. In other contexts we might need it to form a question: ***Do you love me**?*, or to add emphasis: *Maybe you don't believe me, but I **do** love you.* But the possible range of contexts with different semantics / syntax for auxiliary ***to do*** is probably too broad to be covered by a single answer here.

Comment: Do you have specific examples of these being used, or are you asking in general?

Comment: Sorry @stangdon I have heard it somewhere yesterday and don't remember now :( I thought it could be general question. I will edit post if I bring it back.

Comment: @bridgemnc That's OK.  It is possible to answer the question generally, but we could answer the question better if we knew the specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that *You do have to* is emphasising the obligation, usually in contrast with a suggestion (or statement, or speculation, or even an assumption in a question) that you do not have to.

So

> I don't have to, do I? Yes, you **do** have to.

> My researches suggest that I don't have to do this. I'm sorry, you do have to.

But

> Do I have to do X first, or Y? You have to do X. (*You do have to do X* would sound odd).

*You do have to* is odd if there is no contrary suggestion already in the discourse.